# React axios POST file missing in Laravel Request

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, react-dropzone

I am trying to send a file using `React` to a `Laravel` API

On the `React` side, I am first getting the user to add a file using [React Dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone)

I get the file from the `React Dropzone` `onDrop` method:

```
handleUpload = async files => {
  const file = files[0]
}
```

I then use `axios` to `POST` the file along with some extra data to a `Laravel` API endpoint

```
let formData = new FormData()

formData.append('pdf', file)
formData.append('data', JSON.stringify({ text: 'Hello World' }))

const config = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer BEARER_TOKEN_GOES_HERE'
  }
}

await axios.post(someUrl, formData, config)
```

In the `Laravel` API endpoint I can see the POST data in the request

```
return response()->json([
  'files' => $request->allFiles(),
  'pdf' => $request->file('pdf'),
  'request' => $request->all(),
  '_files' => $_FILES,
]);
```

The result of the above is:

```
{
  files: {
    pdf: {}
  }
  pdf: {}
  request: {
    data: "{"text":"Hello World"}", 
    pdf: {}
  }
  _files: {
    pdf: {
      error: 0
      name: "Some File.pdf"
      size: 182552
      tmp_name: "/tmp/phpVRSJV3"
      type: "application/pdf"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the file is present if I access it using `$_FILES`

However, using `Laravel`'s `$request->file('pdf')` or `$request->allFiles()`, the file is not there.

--

I've tried changing the config for `axios` in the `React` side and adding

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer BEARER_TOKEN_GOES_HERE',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}
```

But this automatically gets added anyway with the form boundary

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryxxxxXxXxXxXXXxx0
```

I've also tried adding the data to the header like so:

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer BEARER_TOKEN_GOES_HERE',
  },
  data: formData
}
```

But this does not work either.

I've also tried different combinations of the above with no luck.

Any ideas why I can see it using `$_FILES` but not `$request->file('pdf')`

--

Additionally, the below gives me these weird results:

```
return response()->json([
  'file_pdf' => $request->file('pdf'),
  'file_pdf_arr' => (array) $request->file('pdf'),
  'req_pdf' => $request->pdf,
  'req_pdf_arr' => (array) $request->pdf,
]);
```

```
{
  file_pdf: {}
  file_pdf_arr: {
    *hashName: null
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFileerror: 0
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFilemimeType: "application/pdf"
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFileoriginalName: "Some File.pdf"
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFiletest: false
  }
  req_pdf: {}
  req_pdf_arr: {
    *hashName: null
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFileerror: 0
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFilemimeType: "application/pdf"
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFileoriginalName: "Some File.pdf"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the file was there when accessed by `$request->pdf` and `$request->file('pdf')`

This can be confirmed if I returned:

```
return response()->json([
  'req_file' => $request->file('pdf')->getClientOriginalName(),
  'req_pdf' => $request->pdf->getClientOriginalName(),
]);
```

Which returned the file name.

I think the issue was due to the nature of `response()->json()` and maybe some restrictions it has.

If anyone can explain why, it would it be very helpful.